# Conditional replacement of values in a column

Tags: r

I have the following:

> ```
>     ID           Value1       Value2        Code
>    0001            3.3          432          A              
>    0001             0           654          A              
>    0001             0           63           A                
>    0002             0           78           B               
>    0002             1           98           B    
>    0003             0           22           C    
>    0003             0           65           C    
>    0003             0           91           C
> ```

I need the following:

> ```
>     ID           Value1       Value2        Code
>    0001            3.3          432          A              
>    0001             0            0           A              
>    0001             0            0           A                
>    0002             0            0           B               
>    0002             1           98           B    
>    0003             0           22           C    
>    0003             0           65           C    
>    0003             0           91           C
> ```

i.e., for the same "Code" if there is at least one row with Value1 !=0 then all the other rows referred to the same Code will be set to 0 (meaning that 654 and 63 for 0001 relative to Value2 will be set to 0). If this is not the case (like for 0003 nothing will be done).

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(Value2 = if_else(abs(Value1) > 0 | !any(abs(Value1) > 0), 
                          Value2, 0L)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#      ID Value1 Value2 Code 
#   <int>  <dbl>  <int> <chr>
# 1     1    3.3    432 A    
# 2     1    0        0 A    
# 3     1    0        0 A    
# 4     2    0        0 B    
# 5     2    1       98 B    
# 6     3    0       22 C    
# 7     3    0       65 C    
# 8     3    0       91 C
```

## base R

```r
quux |>
  transform(Value2 = ifelse(ave(abs(Value1), Code, FUN = function(v) abs(v) > 0 | !any(abs(v) > 0)), 
                            Value2, 0L))
#   ID Value1 Value2 Code
# 1  1    3.3    432    A
# 2  1    0.0      0    A
# 3  1    0.0      0    A
# 4  2    0.0      0    B
# 5  2    1.0     98    B
# 6  3    0.0     22    C
# 7  3    0.0     65    C
# 8  3    0.0     91    C
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(quux)[, Value2 := fifelse(abs(Value1) > 0 | !any(abs(Value1) > 0), Value2, 0L), by = Code][]
#       ID Value1 Value2   Code
#    <int>  <num>  <int> <char>
# 1:     1    3.3    432      A
# 2:     1    0.0      0      A
# 3:     1    0.0      0      A
# 4:     2    0.0      0      B
# 5:     2    1.0     98      B
# 6:     3    0.0     22      C
# 7:     3    0.0     65      C
# 8:     3    0.0     91      C
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Value1 = c(3.3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Value2 = c(432L, 654L, 63L, 78L, 98L, 22L, 65L, 91L), Code = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Could simplify `!any(abs(Value1) > 0)` to `all(Value1 == 0)`. Right?

Comment: Perhaps, but I didn't want to guess at precision of OP's floating point, where https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272 might come into play. The `abs(.)` is (again) not assuming guaranteed absence of negative numbers. @sindri_baldur

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df %>% group_by(Code) %>% 
mutate(Value2 = if_else(row_number() == 1 & any(Value1 != 0), Value2, 0)) 

# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   Code [3]
# ID Value1 Value2 Code 
# <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>
# 1     1    3.3    432 A    
# 2     1    0        0 A    
# 3     1    0        0 A    
# 4     2    0       78 B    
# 5     2    1        0 B    
# 6     3    0        0 C    
# 7     3    0        0 C    
# 8     3    0        0 C
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use an `if_else` here. For example

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Value2=if_else(any(Value1!=0) & Value1==0, 0L, Value2))
```

Basically we use `any()` to check for non-zero values and then replace with 0s if one is found.